# The javascript code explanation needed

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, instance

Here is a function:

```
function ShowHelloWorld(){
 this.x=4;
 var y=5;
 return 6;
}
```

**Statement 1. `var res1 = ShowHelloWorld;`**

1.1 So, `res1` is a copy of ShowHelloWorld function.

1.2 `res1()` gets 6.

1.3 There is no way to reach values 4 and 5 from `res1`.

**Statement 2. `var res2 = ShowHelloWorld();`**

2.1 `res2` gets 6 as a result of a function.

2.2 There is no way to reach values 4 and 5 from `res2`.

**Statement 3. `var res3 = new ShowHelloWorld();`**

3.1 Here `res3` is an instance of the function ShowHelloWorld().

3.2 `res3.x` can be reached. //res3.x==4

3.3 There is no way to reach values 5 and 6 from `res3`.

**Statement 4. `var res4 = new ShowHelloWorld;`  // with no ()**

4.1 Seems like res4 is the same `res3`. Why? (I see it is the same when I test it in the browser console).

4.2 What's the sense of this line (it makes sense if it has no errors, right?)

Please answer my questions or correct my statements in case if they are incorrect or could be even better.

Thank you.

Comment: 1.1 and 3.1 are wrong. 3.2 is wrong because of a typo. 4.2 does not return a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `res1` **is not** a copy of `ShowHelloWorld`. It's just a reference, an alias.

2) `res2` is a result of calling `ShowHelloWorld`. The rest is true.

3) Somewhat true. However if you return an **object** (`6` is a primitive, not an object), then `new` will return that object. Have a look at this snippet:

```
function ShowHelloWorld(){
  this.x=4;
  var y=5;
  return {};
}
```

Now nothing is accessible except for the final object `{}`. So if you want to treat a function as a class (i.e. you want to use `new` on it) then it is a good practice to omit the `return` statement.

4) `new ShowHelloWorld;` is just an alias for `new ShowHelloWorld();`

Answer (score 1):

Statement 4 is equivalent of Statement 3 because of javascript syntax. After 'new' keyword should be name of function that will be used as constructor. Params can be skipped.